# Round a Decimal to two decimal places

Tags: apex, math, decimal

How can I round an arbitrary Decimal to 2 decimal places (hundredths of a dollar)?

My first thought was to use the [Math Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) ROUND(*number*, *numDigits*):

```
Decimal toRound = 3.14159265359;    
Decimal rounded = Math.round(toRound, 2);
system.debug(rounded);
```

But that produced the following compile error:

> Compile error at line 2 column 19
>
> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Math.round(Decimal, Integer)

When I think of rounding I typically expect "[Round half away from zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero)" tie-breaking behaviour. Maybe this isn't the best rounding approach to use with currency values?
I would expect the following rounding:

- 1.004 to 1.00
- 1.005 to 1.01
- 1.014 to 1.01
- 1.015 to 1.02

The following works (to some degree), but seems a bit crude:

```
Decimal toRound = 3.14159265359;    
Decimal rounded = Math.round(toRound * 100) / 100.0;
system.debug(rounded);
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I don't think it gets more concise than this:

```
Decimal toround = 3.14159265;
Decimal rounded = toround.setScale(2);
system.debug(rounded);
```

What's nice about this one is you can use the setScale overload that lets you specify the rounding mode you want to use.

```
Decimal toround = 3.14159265;
Decimal rounded = toRound.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
system.debug(rounded);
```

In this case - I think you'll want the HALF_UP rounding mode. It's the traditional round to nearest, but round .5 up.

Comment: That does seem to be the common rounding method. Is there a rounding mode that would round 1.005 to 1.01 and 1.015 to 1.02? As in _round half away from zero_?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've made an edit to include an example specifying the rounding mode as the web documentation doesn't.

Comment: The code above, with HALF_UP specified, produces those results.

Comment: It's worth noting that even though Salesforce calls this "HALF_UP", it is actually "Half Away from Zero" rounding. Traditionally "Half Up" rounds negative numbers differently, with -1.5 rounding to -1 (up; toward positive infinity). Salesforce's HALF_UP rounding, however, will round -1.5 to -2 (away from zero). Similar results are true of the other rounding methods in salesforce (DOWN == toward zero, UP = away from zero, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

```
Decimal toRound = 3.1445;
Decimal rounded = toRound.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);
system.debug(rounded);
```

> 3.15

```
toRound.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

will not return 3.15 from 3.1445.

Comment: I'd typically expect 3.1445 to round to 3.14 at 2 decimal places. That said, I'm used to half up rounding. At least we have the flexibility to defined the required rounding method.

Comment: I asked a few people around me, all of them round 3.1445 to 3.14, not to 3.15. 
My steps was round 3.1445 to 3.145, then 3.145 to 3.15. But this is not how rounding is done...