# Round Double to three Decimal places

Tags: apex, double

Dear all I am trying to round a Double number with three decimal places:

```
Double tl = (tReadTotal/totalRead).setScale(3);
c.CAC_Lectura__c = tl;
```

Doing this it does not work, How can I do that??

Comment: What about this doesn't work? Have you debugged the value of `t1`? What is the field type (and settings) for `CAC_Lectura__c`?

Comment: Does not recognize the method setScale, so I cannot either debug it. The field type of CAC_Lectura__c is Number and Has a lenght of 15 and 3 decimal places.

Comment: Can you submit some value?And the expected one

Answer (score 6):

As there is no method called `setScale` available for [`Double`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_double.htm) class, you are getting that exception. `setScale` method is available for [`Decimal`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) class.

The scale (number of digits to the right of decimal point) can be set for a `Decimal`, but cannot for a `Double`. `Doubles` have limited number of methods available as compared to `Decimals`.

You can refer this [Decimal or double?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88355/decimal-or-double) to understand when to use `Decimal` and when to use `Double`.

In your case, you will have to typecast the result of the division to `Decimal` and then set its scale.

```
Double tl = Decimal.valueOf((tReadTotal/totalRead)).setScale(3);
system.debug(tl);
c.CAC_Lectura__c = tl;
```

This above code typecasts the result to `Decimal` and then applies the scale which can be assigned to a `Double`