# Avoid exponential while converting Double to String

Tags: apex, json, data-types, conversion, jsongenerator

- I was working with integration, where i need to send my internal data
  to Core system. I have came across a strange issue while converting
  large number(Double) into JSON.
- Sales-force automatically converting
  number into exponent. Below is sample json i have to trying to
  resolve,In real scenario my JSON is holding very large content.  Does
  any know how to resolve this issue?

Sample Json format trying to generate:

```
{ "Amount":45454544.00 }
```

Example 1:

```
Double num1=45454544.00;
String str= '{"Amount":' + num1 + '}';
system.debug(str);
```

Example 2:

```
Map<String,Double> num2=new Map<String,Double>{'Amount'=>45454544.00};
system.debug(JSON.Serialize(num2));
```

Output for the above code:

```
{"Amount":4.5454544E7}
```

Core system is throwing an error, because it unable to resolve exponent form.

Question Updated:

Using decimal will still has an issue while converting larger number.

```
Double num1=45454544545546556.23;
Decimal num3= (Decimal)num1;
String str= '{"Amount":' + String.valueOf(num3) + '}';
system.debug(str);

output: {"Amount":4.545454454554656E+16}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Decimal data type:

```
Map<String, Decimal> num2 = new Map<String, Decimal>{ 'Amount' => 45454544.00 };
system.debug(JSON.Serialize(num2));
```

Outputs:

> {"Amount":45454544.00}

Read this question [Decimal or double](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88355/decimal-or-double) for a more in depth analysis.

Comment: I have updated question.. Still issue with larger number...

Comment: You need to store the original number in a variable of Decimal Data type, Double is unable to handle large numbers, so it stores in exponential value. eg: ``Decimal num1=45454544545546556.23;``

Comment: but when i convert from double to decimal it lost decimal point also for large number...

Comment: Yes it would get lost, hence you should use Decimal type